# Is there any way to reduce the size of calendar popup of MD date picker of angular Material

Tags: angular

I want to reduce the size of this popup.
I am trying to modify these classes: BUT IN CASE OF ".mat-calendar" class I am not able to override the width property because they have added "!important" to it

```
.mat-calendar-content{
width: 380px !important;
}

.mat-datepicker-content{
width: 390px !important;
}

.mat-calendar{
width: 465px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some surfing and discussion with friends I came to solution by using property "zoom"
.mat-calendar{
zoom:"0.75"
}

It helped me to resolve that issue.

Comment: I am looking for the same issue, this didn't work for me.
Added .mat-calendar{ zoom:"0.75" } in the .css file.

Comment: As i started working with Angular material, I realised that if you are overriding Css then those classes should be there in common css file(styles.css in case of Angular application) and right below to the theme you are importing if any.(overwritten classes should be at the start of the css file)

Answer (score 0):

There are two options.

1. Switch to "Touch UI" instead of the default dropdown.
   https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#touch-ui-mode
2. TO reduce the size of the dropdown. Add this in your style file.

```css
::ng-deep .mat-datepicker-content .mat-calendar{
    width: unset !important;
    height: unset !important;
}
```